# Checkbox gets disabled if Spinner Theme is used

Tags: android, checkbox

I created a theme and set its:

- SpinnerStyle
- SpinnerItemStyle
- SpinnerDropDownItemStyle

Here is the code:

```
<style name="MySpinnerTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
        <item name="android:spinnerItemStyle">@style/MySpinnerItem</item>
        <item name="android:spinnerStyle">@style/MySpinner</item>
        <item name="android:spinnerDropDownItemStyle">@style/MySpinnerDropDown</item>
    </style>
    <style name="MySpinner" parent="@android:style/Widget.Spinner">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/base1</item>
        <item name="android:clickable">true</item>
        <item name="android:enabled">true</item>

            </style>

    <style name="MySpinnerItem" parent="android:Widget.TextView.SpinnerItem">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/base1</item>
        <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/MyTextAppearanceSpinnerItem</item>
        <item name="android:padding">2dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingLeft">6dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingRight">6dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyTextAppearanceSpinnerItem" parent="android:TextAppearance.Widget.TextView.SpinnerItem">
        <item name="android:textColor">#FFF</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingLeft">6dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingRight">6dp</item>
    </style>
    <style name="MySpinnerDropDown" parent="android:Widget.Spinner.DropDown">
        <item name="android:textColor">#FFF</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/base1</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    </style>
```

I set the theme for one Activity. When I added a CheckBox to it, it gets disabled and I can't click it.

If I set text to it, it gets written *inside* the clickable area.

Here is its code:

```
<CheckBox
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/cboxData"
android:padding="4dp"
android:clickable="true"
android:enabled="true"
android:focusable="true"
android:text="sdsd"
/>
```

The phone is Android 2.3.
What's wrong with my CheckBox?

Comment: I tried it on another Activity, and it can be clicked (though the text still appears in the box). I added the styles.

Comment: I don't understand why this style modifies another widget's behavior. Is it because they are both extend View?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my mistake: I used *setEnabled()* instead of *setChecked()*. No wonder I began to use C#-like properties instead of *setXY* :)